# Problem with dual boot Ubuntu-Windows

Tags: boot

I have one desktop(64-bit) and one old netbook (32-bit). Both of them have windows 7 (only). I have a usb hard disk which has ubuntu (64-bit) which boots without problems from the desktop and recently I installed ubuntu 32-bit (in the usb hd) in order to use them with my netbook. The problem is that although they boot with the desktop pc, when I try to boot from netbook I get the error:

```
unknown filesystem
grub rescue>_
```

when I give **>ls** I get only `(hd0,msdos1),(hd0,...),...`
that is bios (I assume) can not see the internal hdd of the netbook.
Any ideas to boot from the netbook?
Also I provide some information which I got from ubuntu live cd (Try it choice)
from my netbook.

```
              Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]
```

============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

=> Windows is installed in the MBR of `/dev/sda`.
 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of `/dev/sdb` and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    in partition 112 for .

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       vfat
Boot sector type:  Windows 7: FAT32
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  Windows Vista
Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe
```

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  Windows 7
Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe
```

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /grub/grub.cfg
```

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       Extended Partition
Boot sector type:  Unknown
Boot sector info:
```

sdb5: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Operating System:  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Boot files:        /etc/fstab
```

sdb6: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Operating System:  
Boot files:
```

sdb7: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       swap
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:
```

sdb3: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:
```

sdb4: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Operating System:  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab
```

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

```
Disk /dev/sda: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1               2,048     6,146,047     6,144,000  12 Compaq diagnostics
/dev/sda2    *      6,146,048   234,438,655   228,292,608   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
```

Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000170586112 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121597 cylinders, total 1953458176 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1               2,048       976,895       974,848  83 Linux
/dev/sdb2             978,942   272,461,823   271,482,882   5 Extended
/dev/sdb5             978,944    71,233,535    70,254,592  83 Linux
/dev/sdb6          71,235,584   264,648,703   193,413,120  83 Linux
/dev/sdb7         264,650,752   272,461,823     7,811,072  82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb3    *    272,461,824   886,861,823   614,400,000   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sdb4         886,861,824 1,082,174,323   195,312,500  83 Linux
```

"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

```
Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        0475-3980                              vfat       RECOVERY
/dev/sda2        C2CC2F46CC2F33D7                       ntfs       
/dev/sdb1        79b97cb3-a4cc-48a6-afae-f0b5f052eec4   ext4       
/dev/sdb3        F25855325854F737                       ntfs       External-Ntfs
/dev/sdb4        13f706a5-bc41-4060-97c3-d83480b2bf32   ext4       
/dev/sdb5        d58b8f4c-a995-433b-a117-7dc0e0335ee5   ext4       
/dev/sdb6        faf6195b-ba23-4423-9e04-4a027e4da6a8   ext4       
/dev/sdb7        f56eab16-08b1-4f42-b849-5844784cc067   swap       
/dev/sr0                                                iso9660    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS i386
```

================================ Mount points: =================================

```
Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sdb1        /media/ubuntu/79b97cb3-a4cc-48a6-afae-f0b5f052eec4 ext4       (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdb3        /media/ubuntu/External-Ntfs fuseblk    (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sdb4        /media/ubuntu/13f706a5-bc41-4060-97c3-d83480b2bf32 ext4       (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdb5        /media/ubuntu/d58b8f4c-a995-433b-a117-7dc0e0335ee5 ext4       (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdb6        /media/ubuntu/faf6195b-ba23-4423-9e04-4a027e4da6a8 ext4       (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sr0         /cdrom                   iso9660    (ro,noatime)

============================= sdb1/grub/grub.cfg: ==============================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux_proxy ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/11_Windows_proxy ###
### END /etc/grub.d/11_Windows_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom_proxy ###
menuentry "Windows 7"{
     insmod ntfs
     set root='hd0,2'
     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 511C-46C3
     drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
     chainloader +1
}
menuentry "Ubuntu 64-bit" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-d58b8f4c-a995-433b-a117-7dc0e0335ee5' {
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd1,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos1  79b97cb3-a4cc-48a6-afae-f0b5f052eec4
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 79b97cb3-a4cc-48a6-afae-f0b5f052eec4
    fi
    linux   /vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=d58b8f4c-a995-433b-a117-7dc0e0335ee5 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
}
menuentry "ubuntu 32-bit"{
    GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd1,msdos4'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos4 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos4 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos4  13f706a5-bc41-4060-97c3-d83480b2bf32
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 13f706a5-bc41-4060-97c3-d83480b2bf32
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=13f706a5-bc41-4060-97c3-d83480b2bf32 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
}
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/42_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/42_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/43_memtest86+_proxy ###
### END /etc/grub.d/43_memtest86+_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/44_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-1EF3-52B5' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod fat
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  1EF3-52B5
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1EF3-52B5
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    chainloader +1
}
menuentry 'Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda2)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-511C-46C3' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod fat
    set root='hd0,msdos2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos2 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos2  511C-46C3
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 511C-46C3
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    chainloader +1
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu 11.10 (11.10) (on /dev/sda3)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-simple-7198b994-27cc-432b-878d-7644241bd461' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos3'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos3 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos3  7198b994-27cc-432b-878d-7644241bd461
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7198b994-27cc-432b-878d-7644241bd461
    fi
    linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda3
    initrd /initrd.img
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu 11.10 (11.10) (on /dev/sda3)' $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-advanced-7198b994-27cc-432b-878d-7644241bd461' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu 11.10 (11.10) (on /dev/sda3)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/vmlinuz--7198b994-27cc-432b-878d-7644241bd461' {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos3'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos3 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos3  7198b994-27cc-432b-878d-7644241bd461
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7198b994-27cc-432b-878d-7644241bd461
        fi
        linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda3
        initrd /initrd.img
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu 11.10 (11.10) (on /dev/sda3)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/vmlinuz--7198b994-27cc-432b-878d-7644241bd461' {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos3'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos3 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos3  7198b994-27cc-432b-878d-7644241bd461
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7198b994-27cc-432b-878d-7644241bd461
        fi
        linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda3
        initrd /initrd.img
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu 11.10 (11.10) (on /dev/sda3)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-13-generic--7198b994-27cc-432b-878d-7644241bd461' {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos3'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos3 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos3  7198b994-27cc-432b-878d-7644241bd461
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7198b994-27cc-432b-878d-7644241bd461
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-13-generic root=/dev/sda3
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-13-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu 11.10 (11.10) (on /dev/sda3)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/vmlinuz--7198b994-27cc-432b-878d-7644241bd461' {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos3'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos3 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos3  7198b994-27cc-432b-878d-7644241bd461
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7198b994-27cc-432b-878d-7644241bd461
        fi
        linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda3
        initrd /initrd.img
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu 11.10 (11.10) (on /dev/sda3)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/vmlinuz--7198b994-27cc-432b-878d-7644241bd461' {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos3'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos3 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos3  7198b994-27cc-432b-878d-7644241bd461
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7198b994-27cc-432b-878d-7644241bd461
        fi
        linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda3
        initrd /initrd.img
    }
}

menuentry 'Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (14.04) (on /dev/sdb4)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-simple-13f706a5-bc41-4060-97c3-d83480b2bf32' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd1,msdos4'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos4 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos4 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos4  13f706a5-bc41-4060-97c3-d83480b2bf32
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 13f706a5-bc41-4060-97c3-d83480b2bf32
    fi
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=13f706a5-bc41-4060-97c3-d83480b2bf32 ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (14.04) (on /dev/sdb4)' $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-advanced-13f706a5-bc41-4060-97c3-d83480b2bf32' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu 32-bit (on /dev/sdb4)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic--13f706a5-bc41-4060-97c3-d83480b2bf32' {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd1,msdos4'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos4 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos4 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos4  13f706a5-bc41-4060-97c3-d83480b2bf32
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 13f706a5-bc41-4060-97c3-d83480b2bf32
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=13f706a5-bc41-4060-97c3-d83480b2bf32 ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
    }
}

set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/44_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/45_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/45_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/46_custom_proxy ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/46_custom_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/47_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/47_custom ###

=================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


=============================== sdb5/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=d58b8f4c-a995-433b-a117-7dc0e0335ee5 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=79b97cb3-a4cc-48a6-afae-f0b5f052eec4 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /home was on /dev/sdb6 during installation
UUID=faf6195b-ba23-4423-9e04-4a027e4da6a8 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sdb7 during installation
UUID=f56eab16-08b1-4f42-b849-5844784cc067 none            swap    sw              0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=========================== sdb4/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

terminal_input console
terminal_output console
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=5
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=5
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/21_memtest86+_proxy ###
### END /etc/grub.d/21_memtest86+_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober_proxy ###


set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/31_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/31_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom_proxy ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry "Windows 7(64-bit)"{
     insmod ntfs
     set root='hd0,2'
     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 511C-46C3
     drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
     chainloader +1
}
menuentry "Ubuntu 64-bit"{

    GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd1,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos1  79b97cb3-a4cc-48a6-afae-f0b5f052eec4
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 79b97cb3-a4cc-48a6-afae-f0b5f052eec4
    fi
    linux   /vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=d58b8f4c-a995-433b-a117-7dc0e0335ee5 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
}
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_linux_proxy ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode

### END /etc/grub.d/41_linux_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/42_custom_proxy ###
menuentry "Ubuntu 32-bit" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-13f706a5-bc41-4060-97c3-d83480b2bf32' {
    GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos4 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos4 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos4  13f706a5-bc41-4060-97c3-d83480b2bf32
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 13f706a5-bc41-4060-97c3-d83480b2bf32
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=13f706a5-bc41-4060-97c3-d83480b2bf32 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
}
### END /etc/grub.d/42_custom_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/43_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/43_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sdb4/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb4 during installation
UUID=13f706a5-bc41-4060-97c3-d83480b2bf32 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb7 during installation
UUID=f56eab16-08b1-4f42-b849-5844784cc067 none            swap    sw              0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sdb4: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================

Unknown BootLoader on sdb2

00000000  05 75 61 1e 60 f3 18 f2  6e d3 9f 7d 7f 75 f6 cb  |.ua.`...n..}.u..|
00000010  5f d5 1f 78 3c 7a 91 f9  6e f7 d9 ac 21 c6 a6 4b  |_..x<z..n...!..K|
00000020  f4 53 18 37 f0 92 1f 06  e9 31 8c 77 99 25 99 c2  |.S.7.....1.w.%..|
00000030  f4 0b 97 07 d2 13 69 b4  06 63 58 c9 4c 56 10 fa  |......i..cX.LV..|
00000040  36 ad d7 a6 ad e5 d9 36  9c 3d 7a db 0c 5e e8 03  |6......6.=z..^..|
00000050  b2 61 61 41 92 b2 e7 b7  d1 02 28 a6 b3 10 5c 97  |.aaA......(...\.|
00000060  52 58 c4 58 26 90 88 1b  ee d2 9a 4d 52 90 52 21  |RX.X&......MR.R!|
00000070  19 ca 90 1a 9a 0f d4 8e  3c 51 89 cd f6 dd b0 2b  |........<Q.....+|
00000080  44 e8 ab 8a 95 cf e5 d5  31 73 da 66 9a 3b 8f 07  |D.......1s.f.;..|
00000090  e5 de 11 be 76 6a 61 f2  da b9 e4 1f 02 4d e3 a7  |....vja......M..|
000000a0  49 51 c0 58 d5 02 fa 5e  ed 74 e8 fd cd 4e c7 ef  |IQ.X...^.t...N..|
000000b0  e1 a3 73 18 d2 12 1f 87  21 7d e2 77 43 e9 39 37  |..s.....!}.wC.97|
000000c0  fa aa 69 cb 87 38 3c 53  ce 73 5d e2 e7 5e 32 66  |..i..8<S.s]..^2f|
000000d0  a7 ac 09 10 ad 08 48 47  13 ac 01 98 09 74 90 34  |......HG.....t.4|
000000e0  6b 9e 68 c6 35 36 aa e5  7f 68 41 28 19 40 a5 ed  |k.h.56...hA(.@..|
000000f0  0f 14 1a ec c8 58 dd 3d  66 7d ce 98 0e ab 70 8d  |.....X.=f}....p.|
00000100  16 cc bf e9 e1 37 22 7c  36 9f 2e 19 84 a0 65 bd  |.....7"|6.....e.|
00000110  34 1b ad ca 6a f5 64 65  36 e9 5a 14 98 6f a0 76  |4...j.de6.Z..o.v|
00000120  e1 b3 d7 28 ae d4 4f 02  9a c5 53 74 11 93 35 ba  |...(..O...St..5.|
00000130  88 f3 0c f1 d3 4c f3 5c  14 ab 2e 73 06 7b c3 f4  |.....L.\...s.{..|
00000140  90 61 e6 e9 d4 92 7a 95  0c 50 d1 0a 60 70 52 3d  |.a....z..P..`pR=|
00000150  64 81 d0 15 41 61 16 01  75 cc 34 88 b5 73 e9 ac  |d...Aa..u.4..s..|
00000160  fd e8 d9 9c b7 cb 1a b8  d8 5d a8 24 8f 5a ff 64  |.........].$.Z.d|
00000170  a8 43 6b 92 65 ed 32 bc  73 77 73 ae fc 7e c8 54  |.Ck.e.2.sws..~.T|
00000180  c4 a8 57 8d 77 3e 65 d2  5b fd 70 dc 06 ef f7 db  |..W.w>e.[.p.....|
00000190  ed 13 fd 6e ef 44 97 fc  38 df 04 a2 bd 18 d5 09  |...n.D..8.......|
000001a0  45 bb de a8 81 7a e4 6b  f1 f0 1a 7a d7 30 33 8d  |E....z.k...z.03.|
000001b0  c1 e4 d1 a6 2e 01 f3 5c  13 6e 2b c2 35 b2 00 ee  |.......\.n+.5...|
000001c0  33 3c 83 fe ff ff 02 00  00 00 00 00 30 04 00 fe  |3<..........0...|
000001d0  ff ff 05 fe ff ff 02 00  30 04 00 48 87 0b 00 00  |........0..H....|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200

========= Devices which don't seem to have a corresponding hard drive: =========

sdc 

=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

cat: /tmp/BootInfo-F2Q4oQmG/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
cat: /tmp/BootInfo-F2Q4oQmG/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
  No volume groups found
```

Comment: When adding large blocks of text from your terminal, the easiest way to get readable format is to paste the text in, highlight the added text, and press ctrl-K

Answer (score 0):

I need you to give me a picture of your computer's hard drive in GParted using the Live key. This way I can diagnose your problem. You may have completely lost your EFI Partition, like what happened to me. If this happens, I will need to provide you the files to be able to boot into Ubuntu to further fix the prolem.